# How to make a site header responsive?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have a header which contains a navbar, logo and little description.

What do I need to do to make it responsive? The navbar is okay (hamburger icon) but my solution does not looks the same what is in the visual graphic seen below.

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/4f6d7emr/10/

Here is visual of what I want when displayed in small viewport:

[image]

```css
/* Marketing business main header */

.marketing-navbar_items {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.marketing-main-header_banner {
  background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/8KR.svg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right -199px bottom;
  position: relative;
  height: 949px;
}

.marketing-main-header_details {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.marketing-main-header_description p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: HeaderFont;
  color: white;
  /* width: 55%; */
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0px;
}

.marketing-main-header_button-primary {
  background-color: white;
  background-size: 150px 100px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #4834D4;
  font-family: Roboto Regular;
  width: 373px;
  height: 92px;
}

.marketing-main-header_button {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.marketing-main-header_logo img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid marketing-main-header">
  <div class="marketing-main-header_banner">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto marketing-navbar">
          <li class="marketing-navbar_items  nav-item">
            <a class="marketing-nav-link nav-link" href="#">Dla kogo </a>
          </li>
          <li class="marketing-navbar_items nav-item">
            <a class="marketing-nav-link nav-link" href="#">Agenda</a>
          </li>
          <li class="marketing-navbar_items nav-item">
            <a class="marketing-nav-link nav-link" href="#">Prowadzacy</a>
          </li>
          <li class="marketing-navbar_items nav-item">
            <a class=" marketing-nav-link nav-link " href="#">Faq</a>
          </li>
          <li class="marketing-navbar_items nav-item">
            <a class="marketing-nav-link nav-link " href="#">Kontakt</a>
          </li>
          <li class="marketing-navbar_items nav-item">
            <a class="marketing-nav-link nav-link " href="#">Kompetencje</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="marketing-main-header_details">
      <div class="marketing-main-header_logo">
        <img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/hPrhZp/logo_mib.png">
      </div>
      <div class="marketing-main-header_title">
        <h1>SZKOLENIA</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="marketing-main-header_description">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an pro dicta maiorum recusabo.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="marketing-main-header_sub-description">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an pro dicta maiorum recusabo.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="marketing-main-header_button">
        <button type="button" class="marketing-main-header_button-primary">Poznaj Agende</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your block

```
.marketing-main-header_banner
{
    background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/8KR.svg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right -199px bottom;
    position: relative;
    height: 949px;
}
```

to

```
.marketing-main-header_banner
{
    background-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/8KR.svg");
    background-size: auto 1199px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center -250px;
    position: relative;
    height: 949px;
}
```

and it comes pretty close to what it looks like you're trying to achieve.

The thing is you used "cover" as size which will always try to fit at least one of the dimensions into your background. Since background-width shall be cut and background-height is too small to let the edge runs out of the visible part you have to set the height of the background to something bigger than the height of the element to force it to overflow left and right.
The last thing was to put push the background a little bit top offset.

I've chosen 250px to add it to the background height and as offset, because it was what looked best for now. You may have to adjust it a little bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/4f6d7emr/20/

Remember that this is only a solution for your smaller displays where the burger appears. You may add it to your responsive CSS file where you work with media screen.

Comment: Thanks, alot brother